# Are two interacting electrons in an isolated system?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electrons, energy-conservation, maxwell-equations

From your point of view, two electrons are initially at rest. In time, they repel one another, leading to an increase in both of their kinetic energies. If they are isolated from the rest of the universe, how is the kinetic energy of the entire system increasing? Asked another way: where is this energy coming from?

I really don’t know how to proceed. Any feedback or sketches of math for me to further investigate are well appreciated.

Thank you for your input.

Comment: Potential energy decreasing as kinetic energy increases?

Answer (score 4):

The energy is coming from the electromagnetic field.

Electromagnetic fields carry an energy. The energy per unit volume is
$$
u = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_0 E^2 + \frac{1}{2 \mu_0} B^2
$$
where $E$ is the electric field and $B$ is the magnetic field. For two charges at rest $B=0$ but $E \ne 0$.

To get the total energy in the field you have to integrate this $u$ over all space. This cannot be done if you think of the charges as point-like (because the answer comes out as infinity), but for the purpose of doing this calculation you can just model the charges as if they were each a very tiny ball, and then you get sensible results. When the charges move apart the field very near each charge does not change much, but the field everywhere else does. One finds that, overall in the case you asked about, the final field energy is smaller than the initial energy, and this is where the energy given to the kinetic energy of the charges came from.

When we teach this at high-school level, we don't normally talk about field energy, but instead we talk about 'potential energy' of the charges. This is two ways of talking about the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I’ll write a computer program to convince myself of this conservation of energy when considering the field as well as the (tiny) particles. I want to upvote your answer but don’t have enough reputation. Please accept this written thank you 

Comment: If the combined energy is $(E_1+E_2)^2$, and the individual energies are $E_i^2$, then the interaction energy is $2E_1\cdot E_2$, which might be finite even for a point charge.

Comment: What happened to the good old Coulomb potential in this answer?

Comment: @my2cts The Coulomb potential is a way of tracking field energy. The energy itself is a property of the field; that is where it resides. When we say that something "has potential energy" we are really saying that we think the field will give the energy back to the particle if the particle is released, which is true, except that in practice energy can also be radiated away as e.m. waves and then the concept of potential energy breaks down. But you don't need to know that at high school level.

Comment: I disagree. In QM the potential is used, as in QFT.

Comment: @my2cts The Coulomb potential term in, e.g. non-relativistic Schr. eqn for hydrogen atom is a way to account for the interaction of the particles with the field. And in QFT the particles are excitations of some field or other.

Comment: QED Feynman diagrams are based on the EM potential, not on the EM field energy. QED is based on the EM potential. The original post is not about QED. If the original post had been formulated about two classical charges I would have given the same answer.

Comment: The particles do not "interact with the field" in this example. The interact with each other.

Comment: @my2cts This exchange has rather wandered away from the original question. I wrote my answer based on classical electromagnetism. In that theory there is no interaction at a distance. Each charge interacts with the field at its location, via the equation ${\bf f} = q ({\bf E} + {\bf v} \times {\bf B})$. If you don't think the field contains energy then what does the Poynting vector and the energy density refer to? If you don't think it is this energy which goes to the particles' kinetic energy then how do you account for energy conservation?

Comment: Mainstream physics states that it is the potential where the energy comes from.

Comment: Are you familiar with the formula $(1/2)\epsilon_0 E^2$ for energy density of an electric field?

Answer (score 0):

Two electrons repel each other by the Coulomb potential and the potential energy is $e^2/4\pi\epsilon_0 r$. The sum of potential and kinetic energy is constant, so the increase in kinetic energy comes from a decrease in potential energy.

Answer (score -2):

One of the result of the Heisenberg Uncertainty principle states that you can't determine the position or momentum of the electrons can't be determined to 100% accuracy.

$$\Delta x\Delta p = \frac{\hbar}{2\pi}.$$

*This means the electrons were never really at rest*
Where does **this** energy comes from? Very little is known till now.

But as the other answers have pointed out Some potential energy was needed to bring them together which  is lost as the electrons move away due to repelling between them. As the Law of Conservation of Energy states this potential energy gets converted to kinetic energy

Comment: There is no "conservation of kinetic energy" in this case.

Comment: This is not an answer to the questio but a comment. Besides, the two electrons could be together in a trap, so localised and close to one another. If the trap is switched off, you arrive at the scenario in the post.

Comment: My fault, will update the answer accordingly